# onActivityResult (Re) called

Tags: java, android

I have the following situation:

### Parent Activity:

```
ParentActivityClass
{
private Intent intent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
 .....

intent = new Intent(this, ChildActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 202);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  {
  public void onClick(View v)
   {
   startActivity(intent);
   }
  });
 }

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
 {
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

 Log.d("Log", "OK");
 }
```

## Child Activity

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  { 
  public void onClick(View v)
   {
   finish();
   } 
  });

@Override
public void finish()
{
Intent intent = new Intent();

intent.putExtra("extra", ".....");

setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);

super.finish();
}
```

When calling the finish() method of child activity, onActivityResult is called in the parent activity. When the child activity is open for the 2nd time, onActivityResult is not called.

Where is the mistake?

Comment: Try to not override finish() method on child. Check if it works...

Comment: How you are going to ChildActivity for second time?

Comment: If you go button Onclick listener, then you are calling startActivity(intent) instead of startActivityForResult(intent, 202);

Comment: startActivity (intent) is called to start ActivityChild.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see is that you are calling `startActivity(intent)` instead of `startActivityForResult(intent, 202)` within you View.OnClickListener.

Edit:
I'm assuming that you are going to the ChildActivity through the button.

Hope it helps ;)
Best Regards